# jQuery bxSlider animation after slide

Tags: jquery, animation, bxslider

I'm using the jQuery bxSlider to fade in elements on my slides.
What I want to do is to animate(fade in) the elements on every slide using onAfterSlide: function() .
it animates on the 1to5 slides, but it doesn't animate(fade in) only on the last slide.

here is the code. could anyone please help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider({
  controls: true,
  duration: 2000,
  easing: 'easeInOutQuart',

  onAfterSlide: function(currentSlide){
    if(currentSlide==0){
      $("#block").fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
      $("#block").hide();
    }
    if(currentSlide==1){
      $("#block2").fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
      $("#block2").hide();
    }
    if(currentSlide==2){
      $("#block3").fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
      $("#block3").hide();
    }
    if(currentSlide==3){
      $("#block4").fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
      $("#block4").hide();
    }
    if(currentSlide==4){
      $("#block5").fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
      $("#block5").hide();
    }
    if(currentSlide==5){
      $("#block6").fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
      $("#block6").hide();
    }
   }
});
$('.thumbs a').click(function(){
var thumbIndex = $('.thumbs a').index(this);
slider.goToSlide(thumbIndex);
$('.thumbs a').removeClass('pager-active');
$(this).addClass('pager-active');
return false;
});
$('.thumbs a:first').addClass('pager-active');
});
</script>



<ul id="slider1">
<li class="slider1-1">
<div id="block" style="background-color: red; width: 500px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left:100px;">
</div>
</li>
<li class="slider1-2">
<div id="block2" style="background-color: white; width: 500px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left:100px;">
</div>
</li>
<li class="slider1-3">
<div id="block3" style="background-color: black; width: 500px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left:100px;">
</div>
</li>
<li class="slider1-4">
<div id="block4" style="background-color: black; width: 500px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left:100px;">
</div>
</li>
<li class="slider1-5">
<div id="block5" style="background-color: black; width: 500px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left:100px;">
</div>
</li>
<li class="slider1-6">
<div id="block6" style="background-color: #FFF; width: 500px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left:100px;">
</div>

</li>
</ul>

<div class="thumbs">
<a href=""><img src="img/1.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="img/2.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="img/3.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="img/4.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="img/5.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="img/6.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hidding controls. Instead of `hide` use `fadeOut`. `hide` sets the `display: none` where as `fadeOut` sets opacity to zero which is reverse of `fadeIn`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,and I have revised to fadeOut().
but the #block6 still doesn't fadeIn("slow"). It's shown but not animating.. Only the last slides's #block6 is not animating..

Comment: Did it work? If yes please accept the answer, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). You need to accept answer, so that others can come to know about the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not specifying mode: fade, the bxSlider is defaulting to horizontal, while your fadeIn javascript may be overriding that, the bxSlider duplicates the first and last slide for horizontal mode in order to make the transition smooth. What this means is your page is ending up with two "block" IDs and two "block6" IDs which breaks javascript since you're only supposed to have on instance of a specific ID. I fixed this in my slider setup by using class names instead.